# Angular2 animation learning resources

Tags: angular, ng-animate

Are there any good / in depth resources available for learning **animation in Angular2** apart from the basic API reference on www.angular.io ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ng-conf+animation but not yet available - probably RC2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation in Angular 2 has changed many times during development, and is changing again in RC2.  [Here is a resource that I used for an app using RC1](http://blog.assaf.co/native-slide-toggle-for-angular-2-and-animate/), though the technique was not officially available, and undocumented.  As it says at the top of the article, there is a new library in RC2.

I confess that I have not tried RC2, but here is my take.  You don't need an animation library (for most things).  Just use css transitions with `class` and `style` directives.

As an example, similar functionality to the linked article can be achieved with this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
             <button (click)='toggleHeight()'>Show/Hide</button>
             <div [style.height]='divHeight'>
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit
                voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam
                aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore...
             </div>
            `,
   styles:  [`
              div {
                overflow-y: hidden;
                transition: height 2s ease;
              }
            `]
})
export class AppComponent {
    divHeight: string = '500px';
    shown: boolean = true;

    toggleHeight() {
        this.shown = !this.shown
      this.divHeight = this.shown? '500px' : '0';
    }
}
```

[Here is working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/onm5jgKSMZzmvMBstC08?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the plunkr example. What's your take on using an animation library like the popular animate.css [daneden.github.io/animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css) to take care of animations vs having to write and test raw CSS as shown in your snippet ?

Comment: I would definitely use that if it has animations that you want to use.  Animation has been an in-demand feature for javascript libraries, but you can see that css animations are _very_ simple (1  line!) and also very powerful if you know what you are doing (I don't).  Why add complexity to your application code? Styles, including animations belong in stylesheets.