# Slide down animation Angular 4

Tags: css, angular, angular-animations

I am trying to animate my page but have the following issue:
 I have content div on my page, and a button that opens another div above the content. I would like that div to fade and slide in, and the div bellow to slide down/up as well. I created the animation I wanted for the div above that opens on click, but don't understand what to do with content div, example code bellow:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button (click)="animated = !animated"></button>
  <div *ngIf="animated" [@slideInOutAnimation] class="animated-div">
  THIS DIV IS ANIMATED</div>

  <div class="content">THIS IS CONTENT DIV</div>

</div>

TYPESCRIPT:
animations: [
trigger('slideInOutAnimation', [

  state('*', style({

  })),
  transition(':enter', [
    style({
      transform: 'translateY(-10%)',
      opacity: 0
    }),
    animate('.5s ease-in-out', style({
      transform: 'translateY(0)',
      opacity: 1
    }))
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    animate('.5s ease-in-out', style({
      transform: 'translateY(-10%)',
      opacity: 0
    }))
  ])
])
]
```

Should I create some other trigger that will move my content div with the animated one?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

First, create a file where you would define your animations and export them. Just to make it more clear in your app.component.ts

In the following example, I used a max-height of the div that goes from 0px (when it's hidden), to 500px, but you would change that according to what you need.

This animation uses states (in and out), that will be toggle when we click on the button, which will run the animtion.

**animations.ts**

```
import { trigger, state, style, transition,
    animate, group, query, stagger, keyframes
} from '@angular/animations';

export const SlideInOutAnimation = [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
        state('in', style({
            'max-height': '500px', 'opacity': '1', 'visibility': 'visible'
        })),
        state('out', style({
            'max-height': '0px', 'opacity': '0', 'visibility': 'hidden'
        })),
        transition('in => out', [group([
            animate('400ms ease-in-out', style({
                'opacity': '0'
            })),
            animate('600ms ease-in-out', style({
                'max-height': '0px'
            })),
            animate('700ms ease-in-out', style({
                'visibility': 'hidden'
            }))
        ]
        )]),
        transition('out => in', [group([
            animate('1ms ease-in-out', style({
                'visibility': 'visible'
            })),
            animate('600ms ease-in-out', style({
                'max-height': '500px'
            })),
            animate('800ms ease-in-out', style({
                'opacity': '1'
            }))
        ]
        )])
    ]),
]
```

Then in your app.component, we import the animation and create the method that will toggle the animation state.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { SlideInOutAnimation } from './animations';

@Component({
  ...
  animations: [SlideInOutAnimation]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  animationState = 'in';

  ...

  toggleShowDiv(divName: string) {
    if (divName === 'divA') {
      console.log(this.animationState);
      this.animationState = this.animationState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
      console.log(this.animationState);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is how your **app.component.html** would look like :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button (click)="toggleShowDiv('divA')">TOGGLE DIV</button>
  <div [@slideInOut]="animationState" style="height: 100px; background-color: red;">
  THIS DIV IS ANIMATED</div>
  <div class="content">THIS IS CONTENT DIV</div>
</div>
```

*slideInOut* refers to the animation trigger defined in animations.ts

Here is a StackBlitz example I have created : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-muvaqu

Side note : If an error ever occurs and asks you to add *BrowserAnimationsModule*, just import it in your app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ..., BrowserAnimationsModule ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49692976/4420532) for other solution

Comment: Wow this really helped with coming up with a common library of animations to share through our site. Thanks for this. We ended up making these factory functions so that we could configure each animation slightly different.

Comment: Yes actually factory functions make it reusable. Can you show which library you are talking about?

Answer (score 20):

I quite prefer the wildcard operator when working with height transitions to allow for dynamic height content.

```
// Bind to true/false states via 0 and 1 values

trigger('slideUpDown', [
  state('0', style({ 'max-height': '*', opacity: 1 })),
  state('1', style({ 'max-height': '0px', opacity: 0 })),
  transition(':enter', animate('400ms ease-in-out')),
  transition('* => *', animate('400ms ease-in-out')),
])
```

usage:

```
<div #someDiv [@slideUpDown]="someDiv.state"></div>
```

somewhere else or in the template you can toggle the state.

```
<button (click)="someDiv.state = !someDiv.state"></button>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a clean and easy way to implement a slide down animation in angular 2+

**my-component.ts**

```
import { animate, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
@Component({
  animations: [
    trigger('slideDownUp', [
      transition(':enter', [style({ height: 0 }), animate(500)]),
      transition(':leave', [animate(500, style({ height: 0 }))]),
    ]),
  ],
})
```

**my-component.html**

```
<div @slideDownUp *ngIf="isShowing" class="box">
  I am the content of the div!
</div>
```

**my-component.scss**

```
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that's the only thing here that worked for me!